# moodle enrol in more than one course in one action thru paypal

Tags: module, paypal, moodle

I have number of courses in moodle 2.1.3+. As of now I have enabled paypal enrollment for each course. From the student point of view, its really annoying to enrol into course thru paypal one at a time. I want to provide a facility from where student can enrol into more than one course and the total fee of all courses enrollment will be taken thru paypal by one transaction only.

In simple words, a shopping cart in which student adds courses to his/her shopping bag and total will be deducted thru paypal like we usually do in any online shopping website.

Any advice on this... TIA

Thanks - KAMAL

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest taking a look at the Meta Enrolment method. It allows you to enrol everyone who has access from one course into another and can be used to achieve this kind of set up.

To add the method, go into the course you want to copy enrolments **to**, go to *enrolment methods* and then add a *meta* enrolment method. The Config screen will give you a list of courses you have teacher access to and you just need to select the course with PayPal enrolment.

This is a live link, so if someone's enrolment expires they will be automatically removed from the other courses.